# css() with appendTo() is not applicable

Tags: jquery, css, appendto

```
 $('#item').click(function()  {

        $.ajax({
           url: 'server.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data : {temp : 'aValue'},
           success: function(data) {
           $(data).css('color', 'red').appendTo('#item');
         }    
       });
     });
```

The problem is here :

```
       $(data).css('color', 'red').appendTo('#item');
```

while it does takes the data and works well with the appendTo()  the css part is not applicable

Comment: Can you describe what `data` is?  Is it HTML?  Just some text?  You may need to wrap your text in a `<span>`; you cannot apply inline styles to a text node.

Comment: just text .....

yeap works great with the <span>  ..many thnx stager !

Comment: sorry...mistake... 

is this the right way  : 

$(data).wrap('<span></span>')   to wrap my text data ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(data).css('color', 'red').appendTo('#item');
```

try

```
$('<span/>').text(data).css('color', 'red').appendTo('#item');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because data is a string, not an html element, thus why it's not css'd.

Comment: sorry, tap was open and it didn't say there's answers, so I answered.

Comment: hmm..can u help me how its gonna be an html element ? :/